# Checking Validity of Arguments using Rules of Inference

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

Im trying to understand how a theorem or statement is proved using Rules of Inference.I have this example

---

[image]

[image]

---

I really don't understand how they say.***Now p->q may be true with p being false.Then conclusion of p is false.Hence the argument is not valid***

What i know is the proposition p->q is only false when p is true and q is false.From that how can they say that if p>q is true when p is false then conclusion is false.Can someone explain the logic in layman's terms please.

- Im referring Discrete Mathematical Structures by Kolman,Busby and Ross

**EDIT:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But he assume that $p \to q$ is *true* !

This is possible **also** with $p$ *false* and $q$ *true*.

In this case, we have both : $p \to q$ *true* **and** $q$ *true* ("assume that $p \to q$ and $q$ are both true"), and the conclusion $p$ will be *false*.

Thus :

> the argument is *invalid*.

Comment: thanks.I get that now.But if a question like this comes up,what is the correct method to approach such problems and identify whether the argument is valid/invalid.

Comment: @techno - exactly that used in the text : to found a *counterexample*. In the case of prop logic, to find an assignment of truth values such that all the *premises* are true with it **and** the *conclusion* is false; this will be enough to show that the argument is *invalid*. In order to find it, work backward : start with a "partial" assignment of t-values falsifying the conclusion (in this case, start with $p$ *false*) and try to "extend" it to the premises. If it works, you have find the counterexample: if you find a contradiction, there is none.

Comment: Please see the edit.I have added an example.It says that the argument is valid but the conclusion is incorrect. What does the book mean by it.

Comment: @You have to review the def of *valid* argument... An argument is *valid* when : it is not possible that all the *premises* are true **and** the *conclusion* is false (see invalidity of the first example). But the validity of an argument is not falsified if applied to a set of premises that are not all true (see second example).

Comment: okay.But in the second example where do we get the information that smoking is unhealthy?